# C# исключение IndexOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#

Есть форма и подключен файл БД (MS SQL)

```
string connection = Settings.Default.DataClient1;
    SqlConnection sqlConnection;
    SqlCommand sqlCommand;  
private void Edit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int uspeshno;
        sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connection);
        string sql = String.Format("UPDATE Class SET Classification = @class WHERE [ID_class] = {0}", int.Parse(LabelIDClass.Text));
        sqlConnection.Open();
        try
        {
            sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sql, sqlConnection);
            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("class", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
            sqlCommand.Parameters["@class"].Value = TxtEdit.Text; //Здесь появляется исключение IndexOutOfRangeException
            uspeshno = sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            if (uspeshno != 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Изменена запись", "Info", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                TxtEdit.Text = "";
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Ошибка", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Ошибка2", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        finally
        {
            sqlConnection.Close();
        }
    }
```

Все верно с именем таблиц и полей, как можно обработать исключению? Помогите пожалуйста...

Comment: а почему "@class" а не "class"?

Comment: @yolosora хороший вопрос. видимо, привычка экранировать служебные слова c# сработала? Или какой-то пример от dapper'а на глаза попадался и перетащил себе приём. Или привык в SSMS туда-сюда копировать код и лень дописывать declare'ы. В любом случае, эту собаку можно было опустить без проблем - имху, лишняя перестраховка.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В Add тоже надо с "собачкой" указать имя параметра.

```
sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@class", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
```

Comment: Спасибо! Точно я не заметил...